# Doxygen C++ - How to put all macro expansions into a group

Tags: c++, doxygen

If I have a macro as such

```
#define FOO(x) void x()
```

That I would us as such

```
class Test {
public:
    /*
    * @brief My func1
    */
    FOO(func1);

    /*
    * @brief My func2
    */
    FOO(func2);
};
```

Is there a way to have Doxygen, when it expands to FOO macro, put each expanded function into a group?

For example, I would like the macro expansion + Doxygen to result in something equivalent to if I have written:

```
class Test {
public:
    /**
    * @name MyGroup
    * @{
    */

    /*
    * @brief My func1
    */
    void func1();

    /** @} */

    /**
    * @name MyGroup
    * @{
    */

    /*
    * @brief My func1
    */
    void func2();

    /** @} */
};
```

Thus, I would like some way to have Doxygen document that all the functions generated by the macro are grouped together while still maintaining the comments for each individual function.

Please let me know if this does not make sense.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What are the doxygen settings you use that are different form the default settings (`doxygen -x`)

Comment: @albert I am using doxygen 1.9.1. As for my settings, I don't have any different settings at the moment (other than I know I need to enable macro expansion). My intent of this question is to figure out how to achieve what I want.

Comment: I did some tests but I don't see a solution for this problem, problem is that you would like to have documentation of a specific function where the `FOO` is used but in the documentation you want something like `<new part 1><specific docu><expanded fie><new part 2>` and as long as you don't give the `<specific docu>` to the macro too I don't see a direct solution.